# how to consolidate series data and make new dataframe in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I've got dataframe like this
[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmCIg.png)

and I hope to have new dataframe like below
[new data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIVHX.png)

How can I create code for this modification?
It need to consolidate first series data and create new dataframe.

Comment: original: 1 A2C02158300
2 D REC/BAS16-03W,100V,250mA,SOD323,0s,SMD
3 D201,D206,D218,D219,D222,D302,D308,D408,
4 D409,D501,D502,D505,D506,D507,D508
5 A2C02250500
6 T BIP/PUMD3,SOT363,SMD SOLDERING
7 T209,T501,T502

Comment: new: 1 A2C02158300 D REC/BAS16-03W,100V,250mA,SOD323,0s,SMD D201
2 A2C02158300 D REC/BAS16-03W,100V,250mA,SOD323,0s,SMD D206
3 A2C02158300 D REC/BAS16-03W,100V,250mA,SOD323,0s,SMD D218
4 A2C02158300 D REC/BAS16-03W,100V,250mA,SOD323,0s,SMD D219
5 A2C02158300 D REC/BAS16-03W,100V,250mA,SOD323,0s,SMD D222
6 A2C02158300 D REC/BAS16-03W,100V,250mA,SOD323,0s,SMD D302
7 A2C02158300 D REC/BAS16-03W,100V,250mA,SOD323,0s,SMD D308
8 A2C02158300 D REC/BAS16-03W,100V,250mA,SOD323,0s,SMD D408
9 A2C02158300 D REC/BAS16-03W,100V,250mA,SOD323,0s,SMD D409

Comment: can you put the details into the question instead of posting them in the comments section.

Comment: Please check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

Some imports:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
```

Here we create dataframe from data you provided:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a" : [
           'A2C02158300', 'D REC/BAS16-03W 100V 250mA SOD323 0s SMD', 'D201,D206,D218,D219,D222,D302,D308,D408', 'D409,D501,D502,D505,D506,D507,D508', 
           'A2C02250500', 'T BIP/PUMD3,SOT363,SMD SOLDERING', 'T209,T501,T502'
          ]
})

df.head(10)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Then we prepare dataframe with first 2 columns:

```
s1 = df.iloc[::4, :]
s1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

s2 = df.iloc[1::4, :]
s2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': s1['a'],
    'b': s2['a']
})
```

After that prepare and add third column:

```
s3 = df.iloc[2::4, :]
s3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
s3 = s3['a'].str.split(',').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
s3.index = s3.index.droplevel(-1)
s3.name = 'c'

df = df.join(s3)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df
```

Output:

[image: Output]